# How do I retrieve an element id vue js

Tags: vue.js, youtube-api

How can I get the id of an element in vue js? The items are using v-for from the youtube data api.

```
<v-card v-for="video in videos" :key="video.snippet.resourceId.videoId">
  <v-img
    :src="video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url"
    :id="video.snippet.resourceId.videoId"
    :lazy-src="`https://picsum.photos/10/6?image=${2 * 5 + 10}`"
    @click="renderVideo(id)"
  ></v-img>
</v-card>

renderVideo(id) {
  console.log(this.$attrs["id"]);
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: `@click="renderVideo(video.snippet.resourceId.videoId)"` and `renderVideo(id) {  console.log(id); }` (assuming renderVideo is in your component methods)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I originally got an error, but then added id to the vue instance and it worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to answer as suggested:

Assuming `renderVideo()` is in your component methods, you just need to pass in the existing id:

```
...
@click="renderVideo(video.snippet.resourceId.videoId)"
...

renderVideo(id) { 
   console.log(id); 
}
```